# Pilfering std::array all at once instead of element by element

Tags: c++, c++11

When you have a `vector` and you assign the `vector` to another `vector`, elements are copied 1 by 1 and you get two identical copies.

When you move assign a `vector` to another `vector`, the entire internal array is pilfered at once. Elements are not moved 1 by 1.

When you move assign an `std::array` to another `std::array` elements are moved 1 by 1 to the new array.

Why `std::array` does not do what vector does, pilfer the entire internal array at once instead of moving elements 1 by 1?

Comment: Because `std::array` contains an array that holds the elements, while `std::vector` contains a pointer to allocated memory which holds the elements.

Comment: [What's pilfer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilfer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that one container (`vector`) contains a pointer to the buffer of data, whereas `std::array` holds the data itself. It's the difference between creating a class with member `int arr[100]` and creating a class with member `int* arr`. You can more efficiently "move" the class with a single `int*` to the buffer, instead of copying the 100-member array.

Comment: Thanks.  Everyone posted nice answers quickly but I found your example to clearly illustrate how array stores the internal array... of course others hinted to the same thing.  I upvoted the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

The basic point of `std::array` is that its content is purely a built-in array object, with the class providing syntactic sugar, but adding no overhead to the representation of the data (at all).

A `vector` normally consists of a structure that contains at least three items:

1. a pointer to the data
2. the allocated size of data
3. the in-use size of data

When you move a `vector`, you can basically just "steal" these three items, without having to copy the contents of the data itself. You end up with a new structure containing a pointer to the same data.

Using `std::array` eliminates the pointer to the data, which means you can't move the contents just by copying the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::vector` allocates and manages an array. A `std::array` *is an array*. You can no more "pilfer" the array from a `std::array` than you can "pilfer" the integer from an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no "internal" array. `std::array` *is* the array, there is no separate pointer that can have ownership transferred like there is with `vector`. Each array *is* `N` elements worth of memory, they can't be swapped.

Comment: So std::array is a class that has an array member created with value semantics rather than an array created with heap allocation semantics like vector?  Is this the jist of it?

Comment: @code `std::array<T, N>`'s only member is `T data[N]`

Comment: @code: As alexc says, the only member is `T data[N]`, where `vector` would have a `T *data` member. There is no way to swap or "disown" arrays the way you swap pointers, so `move` semantics can't be implemented as cheaply for `std::array`.